# Swift 3 How to change the image size dynamically for different resolutions

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

How to change the image size dynamically for different resolutions

Comment: Use constrain for change the size of image

Comment: can i post answer in objective C ?

Comment: Is your image in XCassets in three different sizes?

Comment: Give constrain of aspect ratio to imageview.

Answer (score 1):

If I -hopefully- got it right, you can achieve this by using *constraints* with `multiplier` property.

Let's walk through a simple example of changing the wdith of an imageView:

Consider the following:

[image]

Currently, the imageView has the following constraints:

- Center horizontally  in container.
- Equal width to the container.
- Vertical spacing to top.
- Equal height to it self.

Note that the width of the imageView is equal to the width of the container (screen) because of the second constraint; No matter what is the screen width, the imageView will has the same width.

After Selecting the second constraint and choosing Size Inspector, you should see `multiplier` option:

[image]

Changing it to 0.5:

[image]

Note that the width of the imageView changed, 0.5 means that "the width of the imageView should be the half (50%) of the container".

It is also applicable for changing the height of the imageView.

Answer (score 1):

Create fullscreen image programmatically :

```
    let width = self.view.bounds.width//full width
    let height = self.view.bounds.height//full height
    let imageName = "yourImage.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , width, 320)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```